# How can I specify include and library locations for mingw32-make under msys2?

Tags: gcc, mingw32, msys2

I have a suite of Windows programs that up to now I have built under msys, one of which uses `libxml2`. I am currently trying to switch to building them under `msys2` and the latter one is hitting a problem. My updated `Makefile` includes this:

```
CFLAGS  += -I/mingw32/include/libxml2

$(BINDIR)/%.o: %.c
    @-$(MKDIR) $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c -o $@
```

But when I run `make (mingw32-make)` the compile fails as follows:

```
[csv-gen]: mingw32-make
gcc -std=c99 -Werror -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -O -I/mingw32/include/libxml2 -c xmlParse.c -o ../../bin/Win32/csv-gen/xmlParse.o
xmlParse.c:36:27: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libxml/parser.h"
                           ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:66: recipe for target '../../bin/Win32/csv-gen/xmlParse.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [../../bin/Win32/csv-gen/xmlParse.o] Error 1
```

Yet that `libxml/parser.h` file does exist under the `/mingw32/include/libxml2` path given by the -I option:

```
[csv-gen]: ls /mingw32/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h
/mingw32/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h
```

And the strange thing is that if I run the exact same gcc command directly from the msys bash shell (copying and pasting it from the make output above) then it compiles fine with no errors.

And I have the exact same problem with the link phase where it doesn't find the `libxml2.a` library in the path given to gcc by `-L/mingw32/lib`, and again I run the gcc link command directly from the shell and it works fine.

So why would gcc's `-I/mingw32/include/libxml2` and `-L/mingw32/lib` options not work when run via `mingw32-make` yet the exact same options work fine on calling gcc directly from the shell?

I did try making the paths explicit Windows paths (`d:/msys64/mingw32/...`) and also tried quoting them, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the answer was to use explicit Windows paths, which as I said above I had tried, but when I tried again it worked so I must have previously made some mistake doing that. I found this by using the output from pkg-config which gives:

```
[csv-gen]: pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0
-ID:/msys64/mingw32/include/libxml2
```

So apparently the problem is that mingw32-make doesn't fully understand the msys filing system, or at least not /mingw32 and /mingw64 paths in it.